# Sortable group for order children elements

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a MySQL table with **products** and other table with **collections**.

Every collection includes some products (but **some products have no collection**).

I store the collection `id` in a product column, like this:

[image]

In the admin panel I show ALL the products, in this way:

[image]

But now I need to make it sortable and group it by collection, looking like this:

[image]

Actually the products are sortable (using **jQuery UI**), I store the order in the database so the products are shown in that order.

How can I group all the products of each collection and re-order that group so the products change the order?

[image]

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the re-order actual logic: https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyadaro/mty2br9n/

Comment: Someone could provide help? ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to format Html something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/u39rapb2/#&togetherjs=7kUmjz8jPm):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- CSS library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Look the EXTERNAL RESOURCES (jquery 2.1.0 and jquery ui 1.11.4)
            $(".container").children('.collection').uniqueId().end().sortable({
                axis: 'y',
                opacity: 0.9,
                revert: true,
                cursor: 'move',
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
                    $("#log").text(order);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collection">
            Fruits
            <ul collection="1">
                <li product="1">Watermelon</li>
                <li product="2">Apple</li>
                <li product="3">Grape</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection">
            Vegetables
            <ul collection="2">
                <li product="4">Lettuce</li>
                <li product="5">Tomato</li>
                <li product="6">Carrot</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collection">
            Others
            <ul collection="3">
                <li product="7">Bread</li>
                <li product="8">Cake</li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Up for Fiddle link. nicely explained.